# Lock clearcase label type using korn shell scripting

Tags: sh, ksh, clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I am trying to lock the label type using korn shell script but I am not able to lock.
As I am new to Korn scripts can some one help me.

Here is my current code:

```
cmUsers="user1,user2";
myuserName=$ENV{LOGNAME};

#checking whether current user is part of cmUsers list or not.

if [[ "$cmUsers" =~ m/$myUserName/i ]]

# if user belongs to cmUsers list, then trying to lock the lable type,
# if it fails exiting the process, else printing the success message

  "ct lock -nuser \"$cmUsers\" lbtype:${label}@/vobs/admin_rec" ;then
    die"Unable to lock label type: \"${label}\"\n";
  else
    print "Label ${label} has been successfully locked by $cmUsers"
  fi
```

Comment: I tried to clean up your Q's formatting, but I don't get if `"ct lock -nuser ...."` is a cmd or part of the comment preceeding.  Repaste from the plain text file and use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box (on highlighted text) to keep proper formatting for code/data/errorMsgs/etc. Good luck.

Comment: Also, learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, in your case `#!/bin/ksh` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. (most of these apply to `ksh` as well). Good luck.

Comment: Your second line looks somewhat Perl-ish; I think you just want `myuserName=$LOGNAME` (or just use `$LOGNAME` wherever you subsequently use `$myuserName`) if you are trying to access an environment variable.

Comment: In fact, *most* of your script looks like Perl.

Answer (score 0):

Beside the **[shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix))**, one simple tip is to avoid using an alias (`ct`) in a script: use the full command `cleartool` instead.
See also "[Ksh Scripting](http://www.well.ox.ac.uk/~johnb/comp/unix/ksh.html)" and "[ksh class](https://www.dartmouth.edu/~rc/classes/ksh/print_pages.shtml)"

```
#!/bin/ksh
cmUsers="user1,user2";
myuserName=$ENV{LOGNAME};

#checking whether current user is part of cmUsers list or not.
if [[ "$cmUsers" =~ m/$myUserName/i ]]; then
    # if user belongs to cmUsers list, then trying to lock the lable type, 
    # if it fails exiting the process, else printing the success message
    cleartool lock -nuser \"$cmUsers\" lbtype:${label}@/vobs/admin_rec"
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "CRITICAL: Unable to lock label type: \"${label}\""
        exit 1
    fi
    echo "Label ${label} has been successfully locked by $cmUsers"
fi
```

However, an expression like `$ENV{LOGNAME}` points to the fact it might not be ksh or any other shell, but rather ratperl (if you are using ClearCase 7.x or more): see "[About `ratlperl` and its impact on `cqperl` and `ccperl`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21245227)"

In which case, remove the shebang, and try executing your script with:

```
ccperl yourScript.pl
```

Comment: I included this script in the previous script(which creates the label type). When I try to run the script it shows me errors from my previous script lines. But again when I try to execute my previous script without adding it runs well. What do you think the may be?

Comment: @clearclase I think this script is not meant to be included. It is meant to be run as a standalone script.